# How do you make Invoker cast a Deafening Blast that comes out all around him?

Tags: dota-2

I'm currently trying out Invoker in Dota 2 and I was browsing through some videos and saw a Deafening Blast the comes out from all sides of Invoker (not just in front of him). How do you do that? When I try it out in Demo Hero, I can only cast Deafening Blast in front of Invoker.

[Here is what I mean.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8KQj6bZ8Lo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AoE upgrade to Deafening Blast is one of the two level 25 Talents for Invoker.

Comment: offtop: in good old days it was just caused by maxed orbs, not by some crappy talent hack

Comment: @Sanctus In good old days this 360° deafening blast didn't even exist, and was always linear.

Comment: One can argue even more: in good old days it was orb order-dependent invoke

Comment: In good old days Dota didn't even exist and kids used to socialize on the streets instead of staring to a screen